# Use li containg text for a new li list with unique input field

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Basically i just want to click on a certain `ul li` and that should populate an list for each one clicked with an input field.

```
<ul id="cultsSelect" >
    <li>randomtext 1</li>
    <li>randomtext 2</li>
    <li>randomtext 3</li>
</ul>

<ul id="newList" >

</ul>
```

So if user click on an `li` i want the text to add to a new list uniquely with an input field containing unique `name` attribute.

**Expected Outcome:**

(if clicked on the 1st and 3rd `li` from above)

```
<ul id="newList" >
    <li>randomtext 1  <input name="perc_1"></li>
    <li>randomtext 3  <input name="perc_2"></li>
</ul>
```

Javascript: This function adds the text `li` to the `#newList`

```
$('#cultsSelect li').click(function() {
 //var input = '<input id"perc_"+count>'
 $(this).clone().appendTo('#newList');

 //document.getElementById('').innerHTML += input;   
})
```

My problem is making each added `li` unique same with the input `name`. I did try using a for loop but got stuck with endless looping that is why i commented out some stuff.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this?

```
$(document).on('click', '#cultsSelect li:not(.clicked)', function() {
 //var input = '<input id"perc_"+count>'
 $(this).addClass('clicked').clone().appendTo('#newList');

 //document.getElementById('').innerHTML += input;   
})
```

You can remember which element is already clicked by adding a class/data-* attribute and later listening for click on only those elements which do not have that particular class/data-* attribute set.

Answer (score 0):

So you can have a variable `count` that will increment each time new `li` element is clicked. Then you can use the `delegation event` to listen only to the `li` element that is clicked.

```js
var count = 0;
$('#cultsSelect').on("click","li",function() {
  count++;
  var name = "perc_"+count;
  var element = '<input name="' + name + '">'
  
  //get the text of the li
  var text = $(this).text();
  //add to new List
  $('#newList').append('<li>'+ text + element + '</li>');
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="cultsSelect" >
    <li>randomtext 1</li>
    <li>randomtext 2</li>
    <li>randomtext 3</li>
</ul>

<div>New list </div>

<ul id="newList" >

</ul>
```

Comment: nice! but how do you add this input with the text to `#newList`

Comment: i does not add the text asweel, but ill sort that outm thanks for the HELP!!

Comment: works 100% with the input, your code snippet would not work , some missing closing tags, and comments.

Comment: what is missing @Ylama?

Comment: the text of the li clicked on.. it should come with the new input. so it would be `randomtext 1 [input]`

Comment: @Ylama , I have updated my answer. You can check it now.

Comment: i cant see the update, maybe its a glitch , i edited your code adding the closing tags, and i think this just made that i cant see your edit?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/159463/discussion-between-edkeveked-and-ylama).